# Postgresql - "is not distinct from" is taking long time to complete the query

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I am using Postgresql db. Previously I was using the = operator to check if a record already exists or not in the table.

Example: I am using only 3 columns in the following query but I have around 20 columns in my original query.

```
 INSERT INTO book_details (user_name,day_of_use,attempts)
select card_number,day_of_use,attempts from temp_book_details temp1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM book_details raw1 WHERE 
raw1.user_name = temp1.card_number and  
raw1.day_of_use = temp1.day_of_use and 
raw1.attempts = temp1.attempts );
```

But I was getting weird results while checking against null values in the column so I found another solution using "is not distinct from"

```
INSERT INTO book_details (user_name,day_of_use,attempts)
select card_number,day_of_use,attempts from temp_book_details temp1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM book_details raw1 WHERE 
raw1.user_name is not distinct from temp1.card_number and  
raw1.day_of_use is not distinct from temp1.day_of_use and 
raw1.attempts is not distinct from temp1.attempts );
```

Now I have too much data in the table and I noticed insert/update query using "is not distinct from" is taking too long to complete the query if I compare the query execution time with a query using = operator.

How I can handle or change the query that will result in a valid comparison with a null column value comparison and it will not take more time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any join that does not have a join condition with `=` can only be processes as a nested loop join, and that is obviously too slow in your case.

Try converting it to an `=` with constructs like this:

```
WHERE coalesce(aw1.user_name, '') = coalesce(temp1.card_number, '')
```

This is of course only equivalent if no empty strings occur in the column, else try with some other string.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

One quick thing to try would be converting the not exists to a left join:

```
INSERT INTO book_details (user_name,day_of_use,attempts)
select card_number,day_of_use,attempts 
from temp_book_details temp1 
left join book_details raw1 ON 
raw1.user_name is not distinct from temp1.card_number and  
raw1.day_of_use is not distinct from temp1.day_of_use and 
raw1.attempts is not distinct from temp1.attempts
where raw1.id IS NULL; --use whatever field would have to be non-null in the book_details page
```